# How to be in-sync with the contact details?

Tags: android, android-contacts, addressbook

### Background

Suppose you show some information (name, phone, image,...) of a contact from your device's address book.

If the user goes to another app (or even the address book) , and decides to update the contact (or delete it), and then returns back to your app, the shown information should be updated.

### The problem

I ask this because I remember that a long time ago there was a way to have some sort of a listener for contacts updates, but it was called so many times without telling you what was updated and have a lot of false-positives, making it quite useless. I was hoping that nowadays there is a better way to stay in-sync with contact details.

This can be a problem if you show a lot of information (a list of contacts, or a lot of information about current contact). Not just in terms of performance (depends on amount of information and speed of device), but also in terms of UX. As an example, if you wish to show an animation when a contact photo has changed, I don't think you can do it, because you can't know if the bitmap has changed. A bad workaround would be to compare pixel-by-pixel...

### The question

Is there any good way to check if the contact was updated since last time you've shown it, and only then refresh the content with the new one? Or should you just always load everything?

Comment: `Or should you just always load everything?` is it really a problem with it? does it take long time or what?

Comment: Can you please post the code where updating information

Comment: Generally I update the whole set together.

Comment: @pskink It's not much a matter of performance, though it is quite a bad thing to load everything all the time, especially if you show a lot of information including images. But if you wish, here's an example scenario: suppose you wish to animate the photo of the person when it got loaded/updated. Now you can't because you need to know if the image was really updated. As a workaround, you will probably need to compare pixel by pixel of the bitmap before and the bitmap after the new loading.

Comment: @PradipPramanick Updating the information is available via the address book app, for example. Code is irrelevant here as there are plenty of places to look for this, and I can show either a single field of a person or all that I can get.

Comment: @KNeerajLal What if you show a list of contacts? Do you always load the entire list?

Comment: no, use `ContentResolver#registerContentObserver` and `android.database.CursorJoiner`

Comment: @pskink As I remember, this is the one that gives you a lot of false positives, and also doesn't tell you which contact has changed, let alone what has changed within the contact. About CursorJoiner , I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: if not familiar then google it

Comment: @pskink I'm not sure, but it seems CursorJoiner is just for the query itself, joining multiple tables/columns somehow. I don't think it's related to what I asked (though might be useful)

Comment: what have you googled? except `developer.android.com` and `stackoverflow.com` sites of course...

Comment: @pskink Those are the most important ones.

Comment: those are the less important ones: google docs just sucks (compared to "nibbled apple" or M$) and 95% of SO as well